# Searching for a commercial C++ licensing library

Tags: c++, security, api, licensing

I am finding a commercial C++ library that provides licensing API to use within my product. It should be:

- Generate license based on hardware information (e.g MAC, hard disk...)
- License could carry additional custom information
- Provide both standalone mode and client/server mode
- License for selected features ( my product has several features and I want to control issuing license for them separately)
- Stable and cross-platform (Windows 32/64, Linux 32/64)
- Good supporting service

I found a product of Nglogic: http://nglogic.com/products/LicenceLib/product_master that is pretty close matching to my requirements but I don't know anything about this company. If anyone have used it before, please give me your comments.

I welcome another suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [LM-X License Manager](http://www.x-formation.com/lm-x_license_manager/index.html) by X-Formation. It provides all features that you list. Customer support is excellent with very fast response times.

Comment: Thank Johannes. LM-X License Manager is also very promising.

Answer (score 1):

I believe FlexNet Publisher (formerly FlexLM) would fit these criteria. They've been around for ages (10+ years) and are very widely used.

Comment: Thank Alex for your good recommendation. FlexNet Embedded is promising. I will check it out.